# When I click link new Page isn't opened on the small tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, href

```
 <a href="#" id="signinFace" >Sign in With Facebook</a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                      $("#signinFace").click(function () {
                            $(this).attr('href', 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=' +
                            '5649219384156&' +
                            'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4151%2FMainPage.aspx&' +
                            'response_type=code&' +
                            'scope=email,user_birthday,user_location&' +
                            'display=popup')    
                        });
                    });
```

What Should I do When I `click`  `Sign in With Facebook` , new page would be opened on a new and small tab ? I thought hat `display=popup` is enough for this. But It is opened on the same window. I also tried `<a href="#" id="signinFace" target="_blank" ></a>` , but nothinhg changed.

Comment: Try to click on link twice, as you are changing the `href` attribute on first click. So I meant that your code isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 <a href="#" id="signinFace" >Sign in With Facebook</a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                      $("#signinFace").click(function (e) {
                            event.preventDefault();
window.open("Your URL HERE",windowName,'height=200,width=150');
                        });
                    });
</script>
```

Comment: it works. thank you
When I click,  `Faceook authentication display` is opened in new and small window.
When I type my email and password and click enter,  is it possible that this small window will be close and user will return previous big window
.
May be it is differert question, If it is so, I can ask it later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `window.open` will not open in new window, So use `target = "_blank"`

```
<a href="#" id="signinFace" >Sign in With Facebook</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".signinFace").click(function(){
    $(this).target = "_blank";
    window.location= 'URL_HERE'; 
    return false;     
    });
    });
    </script>
```